# Validate UID in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, uid, regex-look-ahead

I want to validate a UID based on the following conditions:

1. at least two uppercase letters
2. at least three digits
3. must only contain alphanumeric characters (a-z,A-Z,0-9)
4. no character should repeat
5. must be exactly 10 characters

This is the correct regex:
`re.match(r'^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(?:.*\d){3,})(?!.*(.).*\1)[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$', input())`

The following two are my solutions:

```
#A  re.match(r'^(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*\d){3,})(?!.*(.).*\1)[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$',input())
#B  re.match(r'^(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*\d{3,})(?!.*(.).*\1)[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$',input())
```

> A cannot match anything
> B can only match a few cases like:'AhBUw9r675','41726EHJIr','X6543g08QS',
> cantnot match cases like: 'yD09Ee83fJ','96R5ZDJg72','r57tH100Ej','h7AFN4y5dt'....etc

My question is why both of my solutions are wrong, and more specifically

> for A: what are the differences between capturing and non-capturing group besides that one can return the match and be referenced while the other only search for match but return nothing

> for B: when using lookahead or lookbehind assertion, when do I need to put the pattern in or not in () e.g. (?= pattern) (?= (pattern))

Comment: For A, capture groups are numbered from left to right, so `(?!.*(.).*\1)` becomes wrong because `(.)` is the 3rd capture group => `(?!.*(.).*\3)`

Comment: For B: `(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})` search for consecutive letters only.

Comment: Note that `^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:.*\d){3})(?!.*(.).*\1)[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$` is correct too but shorter (we don't care if there are more than two capital letters, only two suffices).

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything is clear. I have one last question which is about the use of .*. I was not very sure why I added it but just feel I should. Can you explain the difference if without the .*  like this '(?=[A-Z]{2,})'  @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: Sorry but if you don't understand what `.*` is, the best advice I can give you is to read a tutorial about regex (even if you understand `.*`, it is a good advice too). About lookaheads or lookbehinds, you have to understand that they are assertions for the current position, and they contain nothing more than a subpattern that describes the string from this position. `(?=[A-Z])` means "a capital letter at the current position", `(?=.*[A-Z])` means "a capital letter at the current position or after it".

Comment: It's the''current position'' that I dont quite understand. I understand the common situation like '123(?=abc)' or (?<=abc)123' because here "current position" means before or after 123. But for '(?=[A-Z])'  where there is nothing around the assertion I don't know what current refers to, but I ran some test and come up with the following understanding: searching position begins from the left position of the first character in a string and ends in the right position of the last character, so for '(?=[A-Z])' means the first character must be an uppercase letter, right?@CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: this might be insightful to you: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Comment: This might be an optimized version of what you want: `^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:\D*\d){3})(?!.*(.).*\1)[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}` see: https://regex101.com/r/iDa1yi/latest

Comment: @user23485271: The current position is the index of the subject string where the regex engine is trying the current part of the pattern. I suggest the book "Mastering Regex" from Jeff Friedl, If you want a good understanding of how the regex engine works. (You can find old editions for free with a little search).